# Return result of SBT task to stdout

Tags: scala, sbt

How can I return the result of an `sbt` task to `stdout`?

Say I have a task in sbt that returns a `java.io.File`, how can I run `sbt` return just the result of the task? Without any `[success]` messages or other logging?

e.g. if `sbt "show foo"` returns

```
...
[info] Lots of output noise
[info]   /usr/local/foo/bar
[success] Total time: 43 s, completed ...
```

I want `echo $(sbt show foo)` to return something like

```
/usr/local/foo/bar
```

For context, the returned file will be used in a shell script, moved elsewhere etc.

Comment: the command you want is `show` not `inspect`, but the output won't be clean enough probably for your script, unless you do some work to parse it out.

Comment: @SteveWaldman, I was using the output from `inspect` to show that the return type was a File but I can see how that might be confusing. I'll update it.

Comment: I think this is not possible without parsing full sbt output to extract that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `print` command similar to `show` to print result of any possible task and the `--error` global log level flag.

The format is following:

```sh
sbt "print <task you want to print>" --error
```

SBT logging docs

- https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Tasks.html#Streams%3A+Per-task+logging
- https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Logging.html

**Simple example.**

*build.sbt*

```scala
lazy val foo = taskKey[String]("foo")
foo := "Foo"
```

*In terminal*

```sh
$ sbt "print foo" --error
Foo
```

**More sophisticated example.**

Detecting a fat-jar produced by [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly).

*src/main/scala/Main.scala*

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello world!")
  }
}
```

*plugins.sbt*

```scala
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.15.0")
```

*In terminal*

```sh
$ java -jar $(sbt "print assembly::assemblyOutputPath" --error)
Hello world!
```

Comment: Excellent direction! Only thing I'd add is specifically with `assembly` it hardcodes its own logLevel to `Info` https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/blob/074d65233a94d21a5406213eada4ce077959256f/src/main/scala/sbtassembly/AssemblyPlugin.scala#L64 and therefore must be run with `sbt --error ";set assembly/logLevel := sbt.util.Level.Error; print assembly"`

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want to do, is to change the verbosity of sbt. You can do that by adding -error at the end of your command.
For example, if I have in my sbt:

```
val filePath = "/some/file/path"
lazy val getFilePath = taskKey[Unit]("A task that gets the file path")
getFilePath := {
  println(filePath)
}
```

So when running the command:

```
sbt getFilePath -error
```

I get:

```
/some/file/path
```